# Port does not seem to be open, even though listening

Tags: python, c, sockets, networking, server

My server is not going passed the listening stage, even though my client is trying to run the `socket.connect()` function in a loop until connection is made. Is something flawed in my server code?

```
#define PORT 8080
void server()
{
    int serverSocket, newSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    int opt = TRUE;

    //Create socket
    serverSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, 
        sizeof(opt))<0)
        error("SETSOCKOPT ERROR");

    //Configure setting of the server address struct
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    //Set all bits of the padding field to 0 
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

    //Bind the address struct to the socket 
    bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

    //Listen on the socket, with max 40 connection requests queued

    if(listen(serverSocket,40)==0)
      printf("\nListening\n");
    else
      printf("\nError\n");
    pthread_t tid[60];
    int i = 0;
    while(1)
    {
      //Accept call creates a new socket for the incoming connection
      addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
      printf("HERE");
      newSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);
      //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      //for each client request creates a thread and assign the client request to it to process
      //so the main thread can entertain next request
      int error_thread = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, socketThread, (void *)(uintptr_t) newSocket);
      if(  error_thread != 0 )
      {
        printf("\nFailed to create thread, %i\n", error_thread);
        rebootOWASYS();
      }
      else
      {
          printf("\nSOCKET %i CREATED\n", newSocket);
      }

      if( i >= 50)
      {
          i = 0;
          while(i < 50)
          {
              pthread_join(tid[i++],NULL);
          }
          i = 0;
      }
    }
}
```

The server manages to print "Listening", however, my client is unable to connect (does not reach the "here" print). Trying the `nc -zv 10.130.28.130 8080` is not successful, however pinging the server is. My client is looping the `socket.connect(10.130.28.130, 8080)` as long as no connections is accepted.

```py
def try_connect(address):
    global connected
    global client
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.settimeout(2)
    try:
        client.connect(address)
        connected = True
    except:
        client.close()
        connected = False

    finally:
        return [client, connected]
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Code looks ok.  A problem like this kinda smells like a firewall is blocking traffic - especially if you can ping in both directions (i.e. server -> client and client -> server).  Also, using Wireshark to observer the traffic is also helpful.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xl3XI9G.png
I think we can assume the router (Ubiquiti) actually recognizes that something is on 10.130.28.130, and my client is requesting to be connected, but nothing is happening. I checked the ubiquiti firewall but nothing is wrong. Any isolation is shut off as well as any IP or packet protection.

Comment: If it's a Linux server, run `netstat -lnt` and see if port 8080 shows up. If it shows up, then your program (or at least, *a* program) is listening.

Comment: @Arno - all that image shows is that ARP traffic is being passed by the router.  It would be more informative to run Wireshark as you attempt to run your client.  Because you are using TCP you should see a three way hand-shake.  Also, note that in that image you see and ARP request (who has 10.130.28.130 tell 10.130.28.155) but no response.  See https://wiki.wireshark.org/AddressResolutionProtocol for an example of ARP traffic.  Look at packets 13 and 14 in the figure in that article.  Also remember that each end of the conversation can have firewalls on them.

Comment: @thurizas Thank you, Wireshark shows that my pc (10.130.28.155) aims to connect, but the server doesnt respond: https://i.imgur.com/gNfOo1k.png

Comment: @user253751 https://i.imgur.com/FOn11Zh.png The port is clearly listening...

Comment: If you run wireshark on the server do you see the SYN packets?

Comment: @user253751 I can't run wireshark on the server. The server is running on an Owa3x module.

Comment: And now, out of nowhere, I can connect again... Ill keep it running all night and post an update tomorrow!

Comment: Alright, It ran a whole night. Sending packets for over 10hrs. Do not really know why or how, but I guess this post can be closed!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is trying to call the connect function without two sets of parentheses:

`client.connect((addr, port)) # Like that`

Maybe you were overthinking it or I'm underthinking it.

Comment: Address is built out of IP and port. It's just cleaner this way. I assume it had something to do with my AP (Ubiquity ap AC pro)  blocking the constant stream of unspecified TCP packets. I didn't see anything in the logs, but once I removed almost all the internal AP defenses, the packets started flowing again (after ``eth0 down`` and ``eth0 up``)